# CAD applications, Photoshop, SketchUp , Corel apps for Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, cad

I am planning to change from Windows to Ubuntu because Windows is hard to maintain (because of virus threats and expensive security software). But I'm  worrying whether CAD applications such as Autodesk AutoCAD, 3ds Max, CorelDraw and SketchUp, are working well with Ubuntu os?

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run Windows programs you need Windows, having said that there are good alternatives available.

For example Draftsight is a professional but free CAD program from 3ds that has a Linux version.

Also check out http://www.linuxalt.com/